# Debug Memory Graph not showing the allocation graph

Tags: ios, xcode, memory-leaks

I'm using Debug Memory Graph for finding memory leaks.

i'n getting some leaks but i cant see the graph itself.

I get a box with the item name with no other details.

[image]

anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: I have one object in one of my projects that show this too, I think that is auto-retained but I can find why?

Comment: What do you mean by Auto retained?

Comment: Well you are testing in iOS 10.2?, there are some many leaks bugs in iOS 10.2

Comment: upvoted your question, If you have notice about this let me know, with auto-retained i mean retained by one closure or something like this Iam not sure